# Attempting to Ubunutu to Active Directory, sssd.service failed

Tags: networking, samba, active-directory, virtualbox-networking, sssd

I'm working on adding Ubuntu to an AD domain. I've followed several guides and keep hitting the same problem: sssd.service failed.

So far I have:

- apt-get'd samba, krb5, ntp, winbind
- verified that my sssd.conf has domains= as opposed to domain=
- added the dns servers to /interfaces and /resolve.conf

Every time I try to start the services, it fails. THe most recent error received is:

```
Jul 27 14:32:08 VirtLinux sudo[4016]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for
Jul 27 14:32:23 VirtLinux sudo[4027]:   intern : problem with defaults entries ;
Jul 27 14:32:23 VirtLinux sudo[4027]:   intern : TTY=pts/17 ; PWD=/home/intern ;
Jul 27 14:32:23 VirtLinux sudo[4027]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for
Jul 27 14:32:23 VirtLinux systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon..
-- Subject: Unit sssd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sssd.service has begun starting up.
Jul 27 14:32:24 VirtLinux sssd[4030]: SSSD couldn't load the configuration datab
Jul 27 14:32:24 VirtLinux systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=ex
Jul 27 14:32:24 VirtLinux systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services D
-- Subject: Unit sssd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

sssd doesn't log much by default. You need to increase the debug_level in the [sssd] section to see more verbose logs at /var/log/sssd.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. My domain was .local. It seems that even with correct set-up, Ubuntu doesn't work well with .local domains. Changed it to a different address, and it worked fine.Unfortuantely that meant rebuilding the entire domain.

Never use .local.